# How to loop through multidimensional array?

Tags: php, arrays, json, multidimensional-array

I'm currently getting a JSON response from a company's API and converting it into a PHP array like this:

```
$api_url = file_get_contents('http://example.com');
$api_details = json_decode($api_url, true);
```

When I run `var_dump` on `$api_details`, I am getting this:

```
array(2) {
  ["metadata"]=>
  array(5) {
    ["iserror"]=>
    string(5) "false"
    ["responsetime"]=>
    string(5) "0.00s"
    ["start"]=>
    int(1)
    ["count"]=>
    int(99999)
  }
  ["results"]=>
  array(3) {
    ["first"]=>
    int(1)
    ["result"]=>
    array(2) {
      [0]=>
      array(4) {
        ["total_visitors"]=>
        string(4) "3346"
        ["visitors"]=>
        string(4) "3249"
        ["rpm"]=>
        string(4) "0.07"
        ["revenue"]=>
        string(6) "0.2381"
      }
      [1]=>
      array(4) {
        ["total_visitors"]=>
        string(6) "861809"
        ["visitors"]=>
        string(6) "470581"
        ["rpm"]=>
        string(4) "0.02"
        ["revenue"]=>
        string(7) "13.8072"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I'm trying to do 2 things and can't figure out how to do either with a multidimensional array.

1. I need to check to see if `metadata > iserror` is `false`.  If it is not false, I want to show an error message and not continue with the script.
2. If it is `false`, then I wants to loop through the results of `results > result` and echo the `total_visitors`, `visitors`, etc for each of them.

I know how to echo data from array, I guess I'm just getting confused when there's multiple levels to the array.

Anyone that can point me in the right direction would be much appreciated :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can iterate over arrays using `foreach`. You can read up on it here: http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php

Since you're using associative arrays, your code will look something like this:

```
if ($arr['metadata']['iserror']) {
  // Display error here
} else {
  foreach($arr['results']['result'] as $result) {
    echo $result['total_visitors'];
    echo $result['visitors'];
  }
}
```

You'll have to tweak the code to fit exactly what you're doing, but this should get you over the line.

Hope that helps!